# I want to buy ANOTHER copy of a game I already own and give it as a gift to a friend on Steam?

Tags: steam

Basically what the title says - I'm on my friend's wishlist and want to buy them a game BUT I already own a copy of the game - for some reason the "Add to Cart" option is greyed out on the store's page and so I can't add it to my cart?

Is there something I'm missing here?

**Edit:** (Included a screenshot)

[image]

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Done! I don't know if it's the fact that it's a BUNDLE that it won't allow me to buy it? (I wouldn't see why though)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to buy one of the proper "Bundles" that exist on Steam, which are not simply a collection of items. When you buy such a bundle, you get a certain discount off the total price of the items in it, however items that you already own won't be counted.

Let's say there's a bundle with two items that cost $5 each, and the bundle itself offers a 10% discount. If you were to buy the bundle whilst not owning neither item in it, you'd have to pay $9 for it, ($5 + $5) * 90%.

Now if you owned one of the items, the base price of the bundle would drop to $5, meaning you'd have to pay $4.50 for the other item by itself.

As you can see, since the price depends on which items you already own, you can't purchase proper bundles to give away as a gift, since you'd only be buying the items that **you** don't own.

Comment: That makes more sense - it's unfortunate because I really wanted them to have the game, but if I can't grab the bundle, there doesn't seem to be much point.  I'll just get them another game then.

Thanks!

Comment: @TaiM.: It's not as great a gift, but you can just give your friend the money to buy it for themselves.